# How can I disable modifiers applyment when clicking on an object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Thank you for trying to help :)

I don't know why but **everytime I click on an object it applies "Cast" modifier to the object.**

Actually, this might help solve the problem:

I'm a beginner,
I was following a tutorial for a soccer ball.

To make a shape of a ball, The tutor said to apply as many "Cast" modifiers us I can.

It actually worked, but now I'm kinda stuck.

Every click on an object in my project apply "Cast" modifier on it. It also does that in my other projects.

Thank you, I appreciate your help

Comment: Have you tried reverting back to Blender's default factory settings?

Comment: `To make a shape of a ball, The tutor said to apply as many "Cast" modifiers us I can.` that sounds like an uneducated advice, as one cast modifier with a factor of 1 does the job amd adding more of them will do absolutely nothing. Now have you used some sort of script/addon or changed your keymap when following this tutorial? Because applying a modifier when clicking an object is not a normal behavior.

Comment: @L0Lock My thoughts exactly. But Shahar, however bad advice this tutorial gives, I can't believe it told you to change the keymap... so it's not clearly traceable what you did there.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone!!! I reversed the blender settings to default  indeed. Something in this tutorial was not right THANK YOU VERY MUCH